# How can I prevent <aspNetCore /> tag from being auto-generated in web.config when having in-host processing enabled?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, .net-core-2.2

Recently, I was told by Microsoft that maybe in-host processing could solve some of my CPU issues (running .NET Core 2.2).

So I went into my .csproj and added:

```
<AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
```

Now, whenever building in Visual Studio, this gets forcefully inserted into my web.config:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" hostingModel="InProcess">
  <environmentVariables>
    <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT" value="44384" />
    <environmentVariable name="COMPLUS_ForceENC" value="1" />
    <!--<environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" /> ALWAYS RE-APPEARS !!-->
    <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
  </environmentVariables>
</aspNetCore>
```

Notice the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` being set. If I uncomment it, or remove it, it will re-appear.

This is a problem because the web.config goes into my repo, then DevOps builds and publishes my app with the following App settings:

```
-ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Test
```

However, `environmentVariable` set in the web.config completely overrides this.

How can I prevent Visual Studio from messing with my web.config and not respecting my choices?

Comment: You could take a look at the web.config transformation, so you have a web.config for your local and a transformed deploy'ed web.config for your other environments.

Comment: If possible, I would really not like to over-engineer this, and instead just make VS not auto-generate this. But thanks for the suggestion! I just want to enable in-host processing :(